# What happens to the message if there is timeout or the application processing the message crash?

Tags: java, jms

I am currently reading up on synchronous JMS for JAVA. I am trying to confirm if my understanding is correct. Based on what I searched in Google, my understanding is for JMS synchronous method, if there is a timeout occurs, the message will be lost forever. Am i correct?

**My question is:** What happens to the message if there is timeout occurs or the application processing the message crash using synchronous JMS method based on the following example?

Using synchronous as an example, where system A is producer of message and system B consumes and process the message
1: System A sends the message to the queue and commits.
2: System A connection is still available waiting for acknowledgement
3: System B on the other side will consumes the message from the queue with receive()
4: System B consumes the message and attempt to save/process the message.
5: At this point, system B crashes. The message is rollback into the queue **(Am I correct to understand this way)**
6: Assume system B is brought up in 2 mins. System A is still waiting for response for past 2 mins (assuming no timeout)
7: System B will consume the message from the same queue again and commits.
8: Next System A will receives an acknowledgement that system B has process the message successfully

Comment: It depends on the provider, not on JMS.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called the Dead Letter Queue where messages go when the consumer fails to process the message.  I know ActiveMQ has this feature but I'm not entirely too sure if it's part of the JMS specification.  I've been working with HornetQ lately and it has a dead letter queue functionality as well.

http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: hi, thanks for the dead letter queue intro. Just to check if this is applicable for the producer side that sends the message or the consumer side that consumes the message?

Comment: The consumer.  The Dead Letter Queue holds the messages that are successfully added to JMS but a consumer failed to consume the message because of a timeout or an exception.  Your bolded statement is correct in your question depending on the redelivery policy.

Comment: ok i get it. so that means for synchronous setup,  if system B consumes the msg but fails halfway,  rollback to the queue is possible based on redelivery policy for synchronous setup.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean synchronous sending or emulation of a request/reply built over JMS?

- If first is the case then producer will only wait for the provider to accept the message. After that producer don't care about that message and consumer as `JMS` provider takes responsibility for `persistence/redeliver/dead letter/etc`.
  Synchronous sending is only about thread waiting until message will be copied to JMS.
- For the second case there are **2 queues required** (`requests` and `replies`)